# 7zip 7za.exe extracts all files to the folder it is running in

Tags: windows, command-line, zip, 7-zip

I have a zipped folder with subfolders and files within those, which I need to extract with 7za.exe. However, when doing this instead of extracting it correctly, it extracts all the files to the folder that 7za was run in and creates all the folders empty. The command I am using is: `7za e Files.zip -y`.

Why is it doing this and how can I not have it do this?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered an answer here: https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/8668663f/ moments after posting this. Hope it helps someone.

Had to use x not e as found here:

> > Anonymous - 2010-02-03 Hi,
>
> Thanks, I haven't tried this yet. (will do it later back home)
>
> So I assume the command line would be.
>
> 7z x *.zip -r -aou
>
> The original command line did not work at all. It does not seem to be
>   able to find any zipped files in any of the subfolders. Which I
>   assume, the name of the subfolders do not matter much, except they
>   must be located in the root directory of where the 7z.exe is executed?
>
> e.g.
>
> c:\sub1\1.zip c:\sub2\2.zip c:\sub3\3.zip
>
> command line done from c:\  and will extract all 1, 2, 3.zip
>   files from those sub directories.
>
> Thanks again